# Marker size not respected in scatter output to PDF w/ matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, pdf-generation

It seems as though the marker size for pylab scatter has different behavior when exported to PDF? Note that in the image, the bottom left X is large (screengrab from PDF). It looks OK in the png output and the screen show(). They should match though, based upon the attached code. Is this something wonky with PDF output?

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

x=np.arange(1,10)
y=np.arange(1,10)
s=np.arange(1,100,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))

ax.scatter(x,y, marker='x', color='gray',s=s)
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
plt.show()
```

PDF Output:

[image: PDF Output]

PNG Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `s` has a different length then `x` and `y`.

```py
len(s) # 10
len(x) # 9
len(y) # 9
```

Why this will result in this behavior, no idea. But if you set `s` to the same length, maybe like so:

```py
s = np.arange(1,100,11)
```

It should work.

So, full code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

x = np.arange(1, 10)
y = np.arange(1, 10)
s = np.arange(1, 100, 11)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5, 5))

ax.scatter(x, y, marker = 'x', color = 'gray', s = s)
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
plt.show()
```

Will give:

### PNG:

[image: PNG output]

### PDF:

[image: PDF output]

---

I don't know on which version you are currently on, but the latest version (3.3.3) will give a ValueError when running your original code:

```
ValueError: s must be a scalar, or the same size as x and y
```

Which basically describes my answer.

Comment: Ugh, thanks. But yeah, that didn't throw an error for me for some reason in v 3.1.1, which is why I didn't notice.